# how to create *.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d for canonical-kernel-team

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, updates, ppa

Recently I installed the repository for canonical-kernel-team.  I used add-apt-repository to install the ppa.  The ppa did not create a *.list file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

What *.list filename should I create in the /etc/apt/sources.list.d directory to access the ppa?  I understand that the *.list file should contain the following information:

`## deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu groovy main`

`## deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/canonical-kernel-team/ppa/ubuntu groovy main`

I just don't know what to name the file.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no naming convention.  Name the file whatever you want, just make sure it ends in `.list`, something so you'll know what it is.